# Changes not visible after PHP Symfony app deploy to Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, visible, changeset

Recently I successfully deployed my PHP Symfony 4 application to Heroku and it's working. Unfortunately when I'm pushing new changes to my app (`git push heroku master`) everything is going successfully but on the server nothing happens. Changes from new commit are not applied. However when I check git and heroku/master branch, it shows correctly that I am on a commit after changes. Anybody knows what is happening?

Remarks:

- I made changes in PHP files (not in static files on frontend)
- When pushing to heroku it automatically launches "Executing script
  cache:clear [OK]"

Comment: remove the complete cache directory

Comment: How to do that? php bin/console cache:clear???

Comment: no just remove the cache directory from the CLI. eg: rm -Rf var/cache. It depends a bit which OS you use and which Symfony version you use